# Error when using inputting string containing parenthesis as command line argument

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Incorrect command line arguments.\n");
    return 0;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]);i++){
      printf("%c",argv[1][i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

I have this simple code, however after compiling this is my output:

```
./a.out 123
123
./a.out (1+2+3)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `1+2+3'
```

What is the reason this is happening, and how can I fix it? it seems like its the parenthesis which is messing this up. Thanks

Comment: nothing to do with C. Your program isn't even called. Bash tries to execute a subprocess because of the parentheses. Use quotes if you want to pass that.

Comment: Don't calculate `strlen` many times in a loop like that.

Comment: this line: `return 0;` is a very poor return value when an error occurs.  Because a 0 return value from `main()` indicates success.  Suggest: `return 1;`  or even better `exit(1);`  or better yet: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `()` characters have special meaning to bash.  Use quotes to force bash to treat them as ordinary characters:

```
./a.out '(1+2+3)'
```